# Understanding how to use the Google APIs Client Library with Python

Tags: python, methods, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

To improve my Python skills, I tried to read and understand the source code of [Google API Python client](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-Client/).
But I've got stuck and inspite of googling around, I am unable to understand the working of a particular part of the code.

I have made a small program to demonstrate that part:

**`upload.py`**

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import httplib2

import apiclient
import oauth2client

try:
    import argparse
    flags = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        parents=[oauth2client.tools.argparser]).parse_args()
except ImportError:
    flags = None

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'client_secret.json'

# Enter your project name here!!
APPLICATION_NAME = 'API Project'


def get_credentials():
    """Gets valid user credentials from storage.

    If nothing has been stored, or if the stored credentials are invalid,
    the OAuth2 flow is completed to obtain the new credentials.

    Returns:
        Credentials, the obtained credential.
    """
    home_dir = os.path.expanduser('~')
    credential_dir = os.path.join(home_dir, '.credentials')
    if not os.path.exists(credential_dir):
        os.makedirs(credential_dir)
    credential_path = os.path.join(credential_dir,
                                   'drive-credentials.json')

    store = oauth2client.file.Storage(credential_path)
    credentials = store.get()
    if not credentials or credentials.invalid:
        flow = oauth2client.client.flow_from_clientsecrets(
            CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
        flow.user_agent = APPLICATION_NAME
        if flags:
            credentials = oauth2client.tools.run_flow(flow, store, flags)
        else:  # Needed only for compatibility with Python 2.6
            credentials = oauth2client.tools.run(flow, store)
        print('Storing credentials to ' + credential_path)
    return credentials


def main():
    credentials = get_credentials()
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

    file_service = apiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http).files()

    results = file_service.get(
        fileId="0Bw239KLrN7zoWl95Nml2ZUpsNnc").execute()
    print(results)

    results = file_service.list(
        pageSize=10, fields="files(id, name)").execute()
    print(results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

In the line `file_service = apiclient.discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http).files()`, I am not able to find the definition of `files()` method anywhere in the library's source code. Neither am I able to find any methods called `get()` or `list()`.

I have read the library's source code on its [Github repository](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/) as well as its [code documentation](http://google.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/epy/index.html), but have not been able to find anything useful.

Here is what I have tried so far:

By looking at the file [**`discovery.py`**](https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/discovery.py), the function `build()` returns the result of the function `build_from_document()`, which in turn returns an instance of the class `Resource()`.

But now there's a dead end as the class `Resource()` does not have any method called `files()`.

So, how do I find the internal workings of these methods `files()`, `get()`, `list()` etc.?

Comment: But the `Resource` class seems to have methods to dynamically add methods to itself. I'd start from there.

Comment: @Jasper I absolutely dont have any clue on how that is working (I am a beginner at Python). Could you please explain in a bit more detail where to start exactly?

Comment: https://github.com/google/google-api-python-client/blob/master/googleapiclient/discovery.py#L967 this is the relevant function I guess. Add something like "`print attr_name, value`" and code to print a stack trace (https://docs.python.org/2/library/traceback.html) (or use your favorite debugger) to see who is calling this function to add `files()`, `get()` etc.

Answer (score 2):

**(Feb 2017)** Good question! I think I had the same issue in understanding when I first started playing around with Google APIs. Let me simplify your code a bit. Then it should make more sense, and I can also forward you to the correct documentation.

The auth code you used can now be simplified significantly with the recent updates in the Google APIs Client Library. (Make sure you update your Python libraries with `pip install -U google-api-python-client` [or `pip3` for Python 3].) Here is a working example using `list()` -- you should be able to take this sample as inspiration and (re)implement your `main()` so that it works.

```
# authorization boilerplate code
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_id.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)

# call files().list() to display 1st 100 files in My Drive folder
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files', [])
for f in files:
    print(f['name'], f['mimeType'])
```

Below are are some additional resources (videos, blog posts, etc.) I've created for using the Drive API from Python... the code above is featured in the first pair:

- [Listing your files in Google Drive](http://youtu.be/Z5G0luBohCg?list=PLOU2XLYxmsILOIxBRPPhgYbuSslr50KVq&index=4) and code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2014/11/authorized-google-api-access-from-python.html)
- [Google Drive: Uploading & Downloading Files](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) video plus "Poor man's plain text to PDF converter" code deep dive [post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) (*)
- Exporting a Google Sheet as CSV [blog post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2016/07/exporting-google-sheet--as-csv.html) only

(*) - TL;DR: upload plain text file to Drive, import/convert to Google Docs format, then export that Doc as PDF. Post above uses Drive API v2 like your code sample; [this follow-up post](http://wescpy.blogspot.com/2015/12/migrating-to-new-google-drive-api-v3.html) describes migrating it to Drive API v3, and here's a [developer video](http://googledevelopers.blogspot.com/2016/01/google-drive-uploading-downloading.html) combining both "poor man's converter" posts.

To answer the 2nd part of your question, the answer is: the methods your using (and their documentation) are **not** part of the Client Library (`apiclient`, `oauth2client`, etc.). That's why you can find any documentation on them. Notice in my code above, I create a DRIVE service endpoint from `apiclient.discovery.build()`, stopping there while you add a `.files()` at the end.

The Drive service endpoint is where you want to leave it and not dive **into* an API like you did (with the `.files()` at the end of calling the `build()` function). If you leave it at the higher level, you can make multiple calls to an API (and not be locked in to only using `files()`), i.e., `about().get()`, `files().list()`, `files().export(),` etc. Some suggestions:

1. Create a generic service endpoint like `DRIVE`, then use the API calls from there (instead of what you did, which was the equivalent of `DRIVE.files()`).
2. The documentation to the APIs you're using can be found in the [Drive API](http://developers.google.com/drive) docs. i.e., [files()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/), [files().get()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/get), [files().list()](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list), etc. They aren't "Python functions" as you know it, but rather, Python wrappers to the API calls themselves, which is why you need the service endpoint.
3. Here's the [general overview to the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) for further reading.

Final tip: use most restrictive scope you can -- `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive` is full Drive read-write access and generally **not** necessary. Since I only display file names & MIMEtypes above, I only need the read-only scope. You know when you install an app, it asks for all these crazy permissions? This is similar. The fewer scopes you request and the more restrictive they are, the better the chances your users feel less concerned about opting you in. Study [all the Drive scopes](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-auth#OAuth2Authorizing) and find the one(s) that work best for you and your users.

Notice that I use `storage.json` for storing my keys instead of `.credentials/drive-credentials.json`

Answer (score 0):

Just building on wescpy's awesome answer:

When you play around with the various scopes, each time you will need to delete that `storage.json` that is auto created when you complete the google login.

In my case I was playing around with `drive.readonly` and then wanted to start uploading files `drive`, but it had been many months since I had played with the readonly work and I had forgotten how the `storage.json` was created.

So it took me a while to realize that instead of deleting storage.json, I could just have my script point to a new (non-existing) `storage2.json` to capture the `drive` credentials.